# Get PHP to respond to a cURL request with a 200 response while still processing

Tags: php, curl

I have a PHP script that needs to be called with a cURL request, however, the script has a number of timeouts within it and takes a while to finish processing.

Is there a way to respond to the initial cURL request while the script is still processing so the cURL request can close but the data still gets processed and the user isn't left with a huge wait time?

### Edit

Basically my script was a cron job that called an API to update my DB, the cron job could only be ran every minute and we needed it to run more regularly so we put a timeout in it like so:

```
$expireTime = time() + 59;
while (time() < $expireTime) {
    // make cURL request to API
    sleep(5);
}
```

We are trying to move to AWS and keep costs low so we do not want to allocate CPU we're trying to figure out if we can use a lambda function to make a cURL request but if we're getting charged for processing time for lambda functions and this has to wait for the php script to finish processing every time this isn't an option.

I want my php script to be able to respond with a 200 response so the lambda isn't waiting and my php script can finish what it needs to do.

Comment: Can you share you code ?

Comment: did you try my answer?  Even after your edit, it still sounds like what you are looking for.  Place the code before any 'heavy' processing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are looking for.....

```
http_response_code(200);
```

If not, you should show some of your code and make it clear where the issue lies.